# iScroll 5 scrollbars and fade don't work together on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, iscroll

I'm using iScroll 5 and I encountered a problem that occurs on iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1.1.

When using scrollbars = true and fadeScrollbars = true together - the iScroll is not working.
http://jsfiddle.net/GuCC2/

```
myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { scrollbars: true, fadeScrollbars: true });
```

The iScroll will work fine when fadeScrollbars = false:
http://jsfiddle.net/GuCC2/2/

```
myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { scrollbars: true, fadeScrollbars: false });
```

I was wondering if someone else had this problem and fixed it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that problem too, but I think there are not to many people around still using iOS 5. For a workaround you can fade the scrollbar manually:

```
$('.iScrollIndicator').css({opacity:'0'});
myScroll.on('beforeScrollStart', function() {
    $('.iScrollIndicator').stop().animate({opacity:'100'});
});
myScroll.on('scrollCancel', function() {
    $('.iScrollIndicator').animate({opacity:'0'});
});
myScroll.on('scrollEnd', function() {
    $('.iScrollIndicator').animate({opacity:'0'});
});
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GuCC2/3/

Comment: i dont get why this works but it works.... fadeScrollbars does exactly this on a normal desktop browser...